# Retrieving data from a js data object

Tags: javascript

Say I'm retrieving a JSON object with information about a user. One of the pieces of information I get back is a code, indicating their favorite fruit.

So I have **userData.faveFruit** and I know its value will be **APP** (apple), **BAN** (banana), **CHE** (cherry), or **KIW** (kiwi). I need to put data onto the page with details regarding the user's favorite fruit.

So I created this data object:

```
var fruitDefinitions = [
    { "APP" : [ "Apple",  "Red, green or yellow skin, round, white flesh, hard core with seeds." ] },
    { "BAN" : [ "Banana", "Thick yellow skin, elongated curved cylinder tapered at both ends, white flesh." ] },
    { "CHE" : [ "Cherry", "Red skin and flesh, round, green stem, single inedible pit." ] },
    { "KIW" : [ "Kiwi",   "Brown furry skin, oval, green flesh, many small edible seeds." ] },
];
```

So how do I go from having **CHE** to being able to pull out **Cherry** and its description? It seems like it should be quite simple, but every attempt I make simply does not work. Should I be constructing **fruitDefinitions** differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Your fruit definitions object is not a particularly good structure for this problem. Consider something more like `var fruit = [{code: "CHE", name: "Cherry", description: "Red skin..."}, {code:"APP", name:"Apple", description: "red, green...."}];`, then you can use reasonably clean filter/map/reduce calls to do most of the interesting kinds of queries.  If fast lookup by code is the most important, move the code out to the key of a single definitions map object or build an index (one reduce statement would do the trick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

Example using different data:

```
var matches = [ { foo : 'bar' }, { zoo : 'zar' } ].filter(function(item) {
  return item.hasOwnProperty('zoo');
});

console.log(matches[0]) // should be { zoo : 'zar' }
```

You also can just store your object like this:

```
var fruitDefinitions = {
     "APP" : [ "Apple",  "Red, green or yellow skin, round, white flesh, hard core with seeds." ] ,
     "BAN" : [ "Banana", "Thick yellow skin, elongated curved cylinder tapered at both ends, white flesh." ] ,
     "CHE" : [ "Cherry", "Red skin and flesh, round, green stem, single inedible pit." ] ,
     "KIW" : [ "Kiwi",   "Brown furry skin, oval, green flesh, many small edible seeds." ] ,
};
```

so you can access your data like this: `fruitDefinitions['BAN']`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest refactoring your data slightly:

```
var fruitDefinitions = {
    "APP" : [ "Apple",  "Red, green or yellow skin, round, white flesh, hard core with seeds." ],
    "BAN" : [ "Banana", "Thick yellow skin, elongated curved cylinder tapered at both ends, white flesh." ],
    "CHE" : [ "Cherry", "Red skin and flesh, round, green stem, single inedible pit." ],
    "KIW" : [ "Kiwi",   "Brown furry skin, oval, green flesh, many small edible seeds." ]
};
```

for use like so:

```
console.log(fruitDefinitions.CHE[0]); // Cherry
console.log(fruitDefinitions.CHE[1]); // Red skin and flesh, round, green stem, single inedible pit.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a <s>foreach</s> loop. Don't use foreach loop for an array.

Use `Array.filter` method as lxe suggests.

Comment: Don't use a for..in loop with arrays!

Comment: Ups, I just saw the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

could probably done more compact, but as a first approach:

```
function findfavFruit(fCode) {
    for ( var n = 0, n < fruitDefinitions.length; n++ ) {
          if ( typeof fruitDefinitions[n][fCode] != undefined )
               return fruitDefinitions[n][fCode];
    }
    return null;
}
```

this would return an Array

`[ "Cherry", "Red skin and flesh, round, green stem, single inedible pit." ]`

for "CHE"

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to reorganize that entirely, go away from thatJSON stuff and do a complete OO design, it actually cries for that:

```
var fruit = function(code, name, desc) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.description = desc;

    this.getName = function() { return this.name }
    ....
}

var fruits = function() {

    this.fav = []
    this.add = function(name, desc, code) {
        var f = new fruit(code, name, desc);
        this.fav.push(f);

    ....
    etc. etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Access for fruites name

```
fruitDefinitions[0]['APP'][0]
```

Access for fruites description

```
  fruitDefinitions[0]['APP'][1]
```

If your input is dynamic then you can do below code  for fruits name and description respectively.

```
 fruitDefinitions[0][input][0]
```

and

```
 fruitDefinitions[0][input][1]
```

**AND**

When your array fruitDefinitions more than one values, then there would be index number of array instead of '0' which means your structure would be

```
       fruitDefinitions[i]['APP'][1]
       ......
```

Here 'i' is index number of array

But it would be good if the stucture would be as lxe said

Comment: Its an Array of Objects, not an object.

Comment: @Axel now is it Okay?

Comment: No. How do you know it's 0 and not 872367648 ?